# How to save options using chrome.storage.sync?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanna use `chrome.storage.sync` where I link the script file at the options page, but `chrome.*` is [not available in content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), how will I be able to utilize `chrome.storage.sync`?

```
<!-- options.html -->
<head>
 <script src="options.js"></script><!-- chrome.storage.sync not available -->
</head>
<body>
 ....
```

Comment: Doesn't the built in [options page api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html) allow you to access storage? In the example they give, it is able to access local storage, so it probably should be able to access `chrome.storage.sync`.

Comment: `localStorage` is available but Google chrome would not sync that.

Comment: `chrome.storage` should be available in content script. How are you trying to test it ?

Comment: Scripts included in the options page are not content scripts and do have access to chrome.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs on **[`chrome.storage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)**:

> (Through `chrome.storage`...) your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page

So, a content script does have access to the `storage` API and this very fact is actually one of its advantages against `localStorage`.